# How to update data in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to display the updated data in the modal. There is a click function which trigger the testing(data) function below. 
The data comes out right in the function. However, the template doesn't seem to update, it still displays the previous data. How can I fix this?

Script:

```
 function testing(data) {
   const testingLink = new Vue ({
     el: '#test',
     data: { selected: data }, 
     methods: {
       showDialog: function() { $("#test).modal() }
     }
  })
  testingLink.showDialog()   
 }
```

Comment: If you're planning to use vue and bootstrap I highly suggest bootstrap-vue. In general you could make the modal showing or not a boolean value inside data and trigger by changing the data from false to true and back again.. bootstrap-vue will make that easier for you. generally you can avoid using jQuery if you are already using vue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create a Vue Instance in a repeatable function
Try it in following way:

```
   const testingLink = new Vue ({
     el: '#test',
     data: { selected: null }, 
     methods: {
       showDialog: function(data) { 
          this.selected = data
          $("#test").modal() 
       }
     }
   })

testingLink.showDialog(YOUR_DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS)
```